# apt-get update could not resolve addresses

Tags: apt, dns

When I run `apt-get update` (on Ubuntu 12.04) I keep getting these errors:

```
Err http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'false'
Err https://get.docker.io docker/main amd64 Packages
  Couldn't resolve proxy 'false'
Err https://get.docker.io docker/main i386 Packages
  Couldn't resolve proxy 'false'
```

When run `nslookup` on those addesses it works.

`/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Any idea what could cause this error?

Comment: Do you get the errors for _all_ repositories or just the ones you show? Do all errors complain about proxy? In your post, the first one does not. Please post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the output of `grep -Ri proxy /etc/apt/apt.conf.d`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know where to look for proxy settings. `grep -nHRi proxy /etc/apt/apt.conf.d`: `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy:1:Acquire::http::Proxy "http://false:8080";` I'm using puppet and probably after some update it thinks that `false` is a reasonable value for proxy.